# How can I change the color of the youtube player playhead using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I want to change the color of the youtube playhead in an iframe using javascript.
HTML:

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'Example'">
</iframe>
```

I want to change from this
(CSS)

```
.ytp-swatch-background-color {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

to this
(CSS)

```
.ytp-swatch-background-color {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason why you want to use javascript for this? you try use important to overwrite the initial style. .ytp-swatch-background-color { background-color: green !important; }

if you want to style something with javascript you can do it like

```
const ELEMENT = document.querySelector('.ytp-swatch-background-color'); ELEMENT.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```